# Moving a list from python to C

Tags: python, c, list, ctypes

I want to move a list of values from python to C using ctypes, my plan was to pass the first pointer to the list and remake it in c.

So in python:

```
test = [1,2,3]
Circuit.cCore.Add_Interpolation.argtype = [ctypes.c_int,
                                           ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)]
i = ctypes.c_double(test[0])
pi = ctypes.pointer(i)
self.cCoreID = Circuit.cCore.Add_Interpolation(machine.cCoreID, ctypes.byref(pi))
```

Then in C:

```
int Add_Interpolation(int owner, double* pointer)
{
    printf("%d \n", *pointer);
}
```

I keep getting 40075424 out, any idea why?

I'm also open to other ways of doing this.

Answer (score 3):

The correct attribute name is `argtypes` not `argtype`.

The elements of a CPython list are `PyObject *`, each pointing at an object allocated at an arbitrary address (as far as you're concerned). At a minimum the object has a reference count and pointer to the type. For a Python `float` this is followed by the C `double` value, and for a 2.x `int` it's the C `long` value.

You aren't passing a "first pointer to the list", which wouldn't make sense. `pi` is a pointer to a newly created buffer for the converted double value of `test[0]`. I also have no idea why you're passing this pointer `byref`. ctypes should raise an exception there:

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 
expected LP_c_double instance instead of pointer to LP_c_double
```

It isn't, however, because you set `argtype` instead of the correct attribute name `argtypes`. So there's no type check.

To pass a list of numbers to a C function, you need ctypes to convert the objects to the required C type, such as `double`, in a contiguous array. Create an array type using the `*` operator for sequence repetition, e.g. `c_double * 10` for a length 10 array.

```
Circuit.cCore.Add_Interpolation.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int,
                                            ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)]

test = [1,2,3]
test_arr = (ctypes.c_double * len(test))(*test)

self.cCoreID = Circuit.cCore.Add_Interpolation(machine.cCoreID, 
                                               test_arr)
```

C:

```
int Add_Interpolation(int owner, double *pointer)
{
    printf("%f\n", *pointer);  /* print first double */
}
```

You'll need to include the length of the array as a parameter if it isn't a known size.

Comment: Ah thanks although I get the error  
    `test_arr = (ctypes.c_float * len(test))(*test)`  
    `TypeError: a float is required`  

even though i changed everything to float

Comment: its ok I managed to fix it turns out because I was reading in a file it was storing it as a list of strings.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot print `double` that way; `%d` is for integers only. You need to use one of [floating point conversion specifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), like `%f`.

```
printf("%f\n",*pointer);
```

You should consider raising the warning level on your compiler. Many modern compilers can warn about this.